# How to check a PDF checkbox from Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, checkbox

I am filling up PDF forms from VBA in Microsoft Access. Everything goes fine, except that I am unable to check checkboxes from my code.
My code is pretty simple, something like this:

```
Set field = jso.getField("checkboxfieldname")
field.Value = True
```

I tried everything I could think of: 1, "1", "On, "on", True, "checked", etc. Nothing seems to work.

I looked at the SDK: nothing on how to check checkboxes from vba in the documentation, nothing in examples either...

Comment: I'm interested in this technique will you post more of the relevant code please?

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? If you `Debug.Print field.value` what do you get?  Seems like "On" is the correct thing to use to check a checkbox.

Comment: Possibly related thread: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1690501

Comment: See page 37 of http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/access.pdf which mentions accDoDefaultAction method to check/uncheck. No idea how VBA can implement if at all.

Comment: @June7, wow great piece of documentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the answer:
You must set the field to the value specified in its "Export value" property to get the box checked.
In my case, it was "Oui" (Yes, in French).

Hope it will help other people. I couldn't find that information anywhere on the net...
:-)

Comment: The Boolean constant for TRUE, in Access is -1 (Negative 1)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple... use SPACE key. I used the following command

Application.SendKeys " ", True